# Как преобразовать черно-белый чертеж в формате pdf в двумерный массив из 0 и 1

Tags: обработка-изображений

Имеется чертеж в формате pdf. Чтобы нейронная сеть могла работать с данным чертежом, его (или его часть) необходимо перевести в двумерный массив, состоящий из 0 и 1. Подскажите, как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум, задуматься над тем, как из PDF достать изображение, или же сам PDF перевести в изображение

Comment: Через gs (ghostscript)

Comment: А так же для контекста стоит уточнить, чертеж прям в чёрно-белом формате без промежуточных серых, так?

Comment: @Acinit серых деталей в чертеже нет, только белый фон и черные фигуры с черным текстом внутри.

Comment: Могу ли я предложить вам реализацию на Python?